# Is it possible to connect mongo db hosted in google cloud platform through a service account in node js?. If yes, how to do it?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

Mongodb 3.2 is installed in a container natively in google cloud platform. we advised to connect node.js server to mongodb using a service account within google cloud platform. both server and db are hosted in google cloud platform.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Connect a service account"? What is your use case? What are you trying to accomplish in the end?

Comment: You can use a service account within node.js. You will need to
put it in your code to authenticate the service account. Here is
documentation on how you can authenticate the service account
within your code [1] https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication
/production#providing_credentials_to_your_application